# VBA Excel Error 13 Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I have the next code that validate ID into 2 worksheets, it works okay but every time I run the macro I get the Mismatch error and I do not know what I am doing wrong or I do not know if I am missing something, I have checked all the answers before to come here but still nothing.

The error occurs at `Set j = .Range("A:A").find(findValue)`

This is my code:

```
Sub Save_comments()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Range

k = Sheets("List").Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To k
    findValue = Sheets("List").Cells(i, 16).Value
    With Sheets("Historical_Data")
        l = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set j = .Range("A:A").find(findValue) '<-- error here
        If Not j Is Nothing Then
            If Sheets("List").Cells(i, 18).Value <> "" Then
                .Cells(j.Row, j.Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = Sheets("List").Cells(i, 18).Value
            End If
        Else
            .Cells(l, 1).Value = Sheets("List").Cells(i, 16).Value
            .Cells(l, 3).Value = Sheets("List").Cells(i, 18).Value
        End If
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you declared `j` as anything? If not, add `Dim j as Range`. Use Option Explicit anyway and declare all variables.

Comment: Hi @SJR, I did but still the same error.

Comment: What is the value of `findValue` when it errors?

Comment: Please make a [mcve] else it's really difficult to help you.

Comment: I did not think about it, it should be if error do .....?

Comment: I think that error happens if the cell contains an error value so add a check first using IsError or similar.

Comment: @tomjohnriddle it is the file with two sheets: List sheet where I have the macro and the ID to validate if exist in Historical_Data sheet

Comment: I think that @SJR already found reason of your error. If everything is in the same Workbook I do not see reason to reference by Workbooks("US_Projects_Update.xlsb").

Comment: hi @tomjohnriddle I have edited the code, I tried again but still cannot figure it out.

Comment: As [@SJR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7008044/sjr) asked, what is the value of `findvalue` when the error appears? What kind if variable is `findvalue`?

Comment: I have Dim findValue with different Data types but still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your code as follows:

```
Sub Save_comments()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Range

k = Sheets("List").Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To k
    findValue = Sheets("List").Cells(i, 16).Value

    If Application.IsNA(findValue) = False Then

        With Sheets("Historical_Data")
            l = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Set j = .Range("A:A").Find(findValue) '<-- error here
            If Not j Is Nothing Then
                If Sheets("List").Cells(i, 18).Value <> "" Then
                    .Cells(j.Row, j.Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = Sheets("List").Cells(i, 18).Value
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(l, 1).Value = Sheets("List").Cells(i, 16).Value
                .Cells(l, 3).Value = Sheets("List").Cells(i, 18).Value
            End If
        End With

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The reason of your error is most probably N/A value assigned to findValue variable - this means that findValue variable has some error value. Here is the list of potential error numbers:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how a minimal version of your code looks like:

```
Sub SaveComments()

    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Range
    Dim findValue   As String

    For i = 1 To 20
        findValue = Sheets("List").Cells(i, 16).Value
        With Sheets("Historical_Data")
            Set j = .Range("A:A").Find(findValue)    '<-- error here
            Debug.Print j.Address
        End With
    Next i    
End Sub
```

If it does not work, simply try to see what is the `findValue` in the case when it breaks.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! I really appreciate. I got the solution. Have a nice day!